# k-vertex connectivity of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, connectivity

is there any pseudo-code implementation that shows how to compute the k-vertex connectivity of a graph?

Comment: What are you looking for the algorithm to compute? `k`?

Answer (score 2):

I can't post here the code from [this](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/edge-vertex-connectivity.shtml) book due to copyrights. But if you can get it, you will find not only you algorithm, but also lots of other good algorithms with codes.

Comment: I summarized it in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph#Computational_complexity