# computing vertex connectivity of graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Is there an algorithm that, when given a graph, computes the vertex connectivity of that graph (the minimum number of vertices to remove in order to separate the graph into two connected graphs).  (Note that the graph may be already be disconnected).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:
[Determining if a graph is K-vertex-connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115114/determining-if-a-graph-is-k-vertex-connected)

[k-vertex connectivity of a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944005/k-vertex-connectivity-of-a-graph?rq=1)

When you combine this with binary search you are done.

Answer (score 1):

This [book chapter](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~esfahani/book_chapter/Graph_connectivity_chapter.pdf) should have everything you need to get started; it is basically a survey over algorithms to determine the edge connectivity and vertex connectivity of graphs, with pseudo code for the algorithms described in it. Page 12 has an overview over the available algorithms alongside complexity analyses and references. Most of the solutions for the general case are flow-based, with the exception of one randomized algorithm. The different general solutions optimize for different properties of the graph, so you can choose the most asymptotically efficient one beforehand. Also, for some classes of graphs, there exist specialized algorithms with better complexity than the general solutions provide.